# Jenkins Plugin for Kubernetes Deployment (EKS)

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm running my application in AWS-EKS and my Jenkins instance is not yet containerized. To deploy our application we are using `kubectl` command in the Jenkins Pipeline. I'm wondering any best practice or plugin for Kubernetes deployment via Jenkins.

So far I found below plugins which do not completely work with my use-case.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin - To run dynamic Jenkins agents. May not be suitable for my case.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cd-plugin - This plugin is providing the K8s Deployment functionality, but interacting with EKS is a bit of concern with this plugin as in EKS authentication is done by  `aws-iam-authenticator`

Is there any plugin available in Jenkins to handle Kubernetes deployment?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Jenkins X](https://jenkins.io/projects/jenkins-x/), it was created specifically for Kubernetes applications

Helpful links:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/continuous-delivery-eks-jenkins-x/

https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_create_cluster_eks/#jx-create-cluster-eks

Comment: It appears Jenkin X completely changes the software delivery process like moving to GitOps. As we are having Jenkins instance on-premises not sure how it would help on only deployment aspect of Kubenetes platform.

Comment: Is there plugin for jenkins2.X that creates EKS cluster?